# Run a native app with a web app on PhoneGap

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

my question is: Is posible to run a native app using a web app developed on phonegap?, I need to make that, I was reading about is necessary create a plugin to connect with other native app, but I'm starting to programming over phonegap I still don't understand much, and need to create that. But I need some very explicit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a PhoneGap native plugin that will enable you to create custom functionality in native code, and expose that to your PhoneGap applications via PhoneGap's native-to-JavaScript bridge. For more information about plugins and example of how to implement them check this tutorial:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html